# Text box size, displayed post and general layout

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, design, information-display

The StackExchange page layout is globally well adapted to computer or mobile for relatively short questions or answers. However, on some sites, long answers are sometimes required, especially those using spacy typesetting with equations, or included graphics ([math](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [digital signal processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)). Of course, one can expand the text box size, on a post by post basis (I am using Chrome).

- is there possible to "memorize" or set of personalized text box per site, to get it by default each type you post?
- could it be possible to gain a little vertical space, for instance putting tags, "post your question" button of the side?

Sometimes, while working at a post, the question is edited, or closed, or new answers have been given, and the person typing does not see it.

- Would some find interesting to have a small, easy notice of such a new activity somewhere close to the text box, perhaps with a compact color-coded icon, on the side, or the top of the edit text box?